# How to generate a procedural texture in the UV Image editor

Tags: python, texturing, scripting, uv-image-editor, procedural

I'm studying noise/fractal generation algorithms such as Perlin and Musgrave, and want to generate them in Blender's UV/Image editor through Python.

I'm aware that Blender has it's own internal procedural textures, however I want to be able to customize the look of procedural textures with a script, so that I can directly generate perlin noise, etc in the Image editor.

I've found some Stackexchange answers that contain scripts for Gradient and line generation, but I'm looking for a way to generate a procedural noise texture in the Image editor.

Stackexchange answers referencing generation of Gradients and lines:

[Is it possible to create image data and save to a file from a script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/643/is-it-possible-to-create-image-data-and-save-to-a-file-from-a-script/75386#75386)

[Is it possible to edit images programmatically with the Blender API?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15890/is-it-possible-to-edit-images-programmatically-with-the-blender-api)

I'm looking to generate something like this with scripting:

[image: Code doesn't generate the image - image is saved sample of Perlin pulled from Google Images]