# How to export a sprite sheet from animation?

Tags: rendering

I want to use an animation in some code as a sprite sheet - is it possible to export a sprite sheet?

Info: a sprite sheet/animation strips, is a list of images that you can load into most game engines:
https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/tutorials/how-to-create-a-sprite-sheet

Comment: What is "animation in some code"? And how would you want to export a sprite sheet? Please edit your question and provide more context about what you want to achieve

Comment: Thanks, I have updated with a link and a description.

Comment: If you have an animation, just hit Animation button. Before doing this, in Render panel choose png extension to retain the transparency. All the png sprites will be saved in the chosen folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do so by using a mapping node, the thing is that you may lack of precision since this job is done usually proceduraly without messing with normalized values (as UVs) but absolute instead (pixels).

So the idea is to create a plane (or as many as the poses you want to "extract") and with a mapping node pick and fit the proper sprites on them using the spread sheet as an image texture.

A more elegant and efficient way would be to do this automatically by using a python script but then it becomes a pain in the a#s since there is no any bundled / native lib for image processing.

In theory what you had to do would be to parse the JSON file (as is in your example) and get the directions from there for the pixel width/height and the position on the spread sheet of each pose or element.

you may take a closer look on this post : [Crop image with Python script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13422/crop-image-with-python-script)

where is the basic concept of cropping images in blender with python scripting.